# Is Collections.unmodifiableMap performance critical?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a `hashmap<String, String>` which contains around one thousand entries.
Now I have to expose it in such way that it cannot be modified outside class. So I wrote like

```
public static Map<String, String> getResponseCodeSource()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(codeMsgMap); 
}
```

This method is called very frequently. My questions are 
1. Will this cause performance issue?  
2.Is method (unmodifiableMap) iterating over Map or this will perform its activity in O(constant) complexity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Map` returned from [Collections.unmodifiableMap(Map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29) will be a thin proxy to the real underlying map with some methods disabled (`put` etc.). There is no reason to expect it to take a copy of the underlying map.

> Returns: an unmodifiable **view** of the specified map.

Remember however that the unmodifiable map is only a **view** of the underlying map so changes in the underlying map will be reflected in the unmodifiable one. It would therefore be safe to do:

```
static final Map<String,String> codeMsgMap = new HashMap<>();
// Changes in the above map will be reflected here.
static final Map<String,String> unmodifiableCodeMsgMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(codeMsgMap);

public static Map<String, String> getResponseCodeSource() {
    return unmodifiableCodeMsgMap;
}
```

On the complexity question [Sergey Pauk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29162969/823393) covers that nicely.

Comment: @OldCurmundgeon, thx for replying. So I can use same function as many time as needed without hitting any perfromance? I am searching for  "unmodifiableMap" internal implementation for ard 1 hr, it will be great help if you can give me any reference for same. This will help other reader also

Comment: @user811602 - If you must call it many times then do so. Remember that you can call it once and distribute the same map many times. The unmodifiable version will change as the map changes. That is what a **view** is.

Comment: thx OldCurmudgeon, I have changed my implementation as per your suggestion

Comment: I would say this answer is too broad since it covers some off-question aspects. Question was very specific about what is `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` complexity

Comment: @SergeyPauk - Question initially only asked about performance - it was edited to include complexity question after I posted my answer.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon is there a way to see the original question?

Comment: @SergeyPauk - Yes - click on the [edited 23 mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29162713/revisions) - and I was wrong, it did contain the complexity part from the beginning. Clearly I did not read the whole question.

Answer (score 9):

It's a very thin implementation:

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> unmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    return new UnmodifiableMap<>(m);
}
```

and constructor code:

```
UnmodifiableMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
    if (m==null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    this.m = m;
}
```

So as you see complexity is **O(1)**.